# Problem while measuring with regionprops for the first index in the interaction

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image, measurement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7vY.png)

Hi, guys.
So I'm trying to get measurements for each object/region in the above image. But, for the first region, I'm not achieving this result.

I'm using the following code:

```
for index in range(1, labels.max()):
    label_i = props[index].label
    contour = find_contours(labels == label_i, 0.5)[0]
    y, x = contour.T
    hoverinfo = ''
    for prop_name in properties:
        hoverinfo += f'<b>{prop_name}: {getattr(props[index], prop_name):.2f}</b><br>'
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y, name=label_i,
        mode='lines', fill='toself', showlegend=False,
        hovertemplate=hoverinfo, hoveron='points+fills'))
```

The official documentation has had the same problem. [https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html][2]

Is there any solution to this problem?